# Why is my loop not working when I webscrape on R?

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, rvest

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(htmltools)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
```

#import using read_html

```
results <- read_html("https://www.artemis.bm/deal-directory/")
```

#Results are in a list - can look at list by running 'results' in the console

#### CODE - The issuers information extracted

```
issuers <- results %>% html_nodes("#table-deal a") %>% html_text()
cedent <- results %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text()
risks <- results %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text()
size <- results %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text()
date <- results %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(5)") %>% html_text()
```

#This scrapes all of the links for each issuer page

```
url <- results %>% html_nodes("#table-deal a") %>% html_attr("href")
```

#getting data from within the links

```
get_placement = function(url_link) {
  url_link = read_html("https://www.artemis.bm/deal-directory/cape-lookout-re-ltd-series-2022-1/")
  issuer_page = read_html(url_link)
  placement = issuer_page %>% html_nodes("#info-box li:nth-child(3)") %>%
    html_text()
}
```

This code works and the last bit from get_placement gets the information I am after (the placement section) - whichever link I put in it gives me the placement for that informational. However, when i try and loop it it does not work

#here is my issue

```
get_placement = function(url_link) {
  issuer_page = read_html(url_link)
  placement = issuer_page %>% html_nodes("#info-box li:nth-child(3)") %>%
    html_text()
  return(placement)
}
```

This only gives me one value when I need the placement information from all 833?

```
issuer_placement = sapply(url, FUN = get_placement)
```

When I try to use sapply I get this message

```
Browse[1]> issuer_placement = sapply(url, FUN = get_placement)
Error during wrapup: no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "name"
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

and

```
function (con, open = "r", blocking = TRUE, ...) 
.Internal(open(con, open, blocking))
```

Comment: Is `url` an actual vector that you've defined? The error message makes it sound like you are passing in the `base::url` function, and not a vector of URLs.

Comment: In your first definition of the function `get_placement` you internally reassign the argument `url_link`to something hard-coded. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without any problem

```
issue_placement <- lapply(url, function(u) {
  tryCatch(return(get_placement(u)),
           error=function(e) return("Not retrieved - error"),
           warning=function(w) return("Not retrieved - warning"))
})
```

When I pushed `issue_placement` into a data.table (see below), I found found 330 unique results, and no errors/warnings

```
data.table::data.table(placement = unlist(issue_placement))[,.N, placement]
```

Comment: I imagine I did something wrong. But which part of the code did your replace your bit with? I'm relatively new to coding. Is it the last section from "get_placement = function(url_link) etc." which you replaced with issue_placement <- lapply(url, function(u) etc.

Comment: yes, I just  replaced your `sapply()` statement with the above, and it worked okay. Perhaps you had ovewritten `url`, and so it didn't exist to `sapply()` over, or perhaps you were inadvertently calling the wrong `get_placement()` function (i.e. you have another there with a constant url)

Comment: Thank you. When I put this into my code I get values 502-834. How would I see the first 500? issue_placement <- lapply(url, function(u) {
  tryCatch(return(get_placement(u)),
           error=function(e) return("Not retrieved - error"),
           warning=function(w) return("Not retrieved - warning"))
})

Comment: carefully check `url` is it of length 834?